# Evaluate the limit by Riemann sum or otherwise

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ and let $g:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be two continuous functions.

Evaluate:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)g\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)+f\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)g\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)+...+f\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)g\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}$

My attempt:Let $L=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)g\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)+f\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)g\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)+...+f\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)g\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}$

$\log_{e}L=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\log_{e}\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{r}{n}\right)g\left(\frac{n-r+1}{n}\right)\right)=\int_{0}^1\log_{e}\left(f(x)g(1-x)\right)dx$

$\log_{e}L=\int_{0}^1\log_{e}\left(f(1-x)g(x)\right)dx$

$2\log_{e}L=\int_{0}^1\log_{e}\left(f(x)f(1-x)g(x)g(1-x)\right)dx$

$2\log_{e}L=\int_{0}^1\log_{e}\left(f(x)\right)dx+\int_{0}^1\log_{e}\left(f(1-x)\right)dx+\int_{0}^1\log_{e}\left(g(x)\right)dx+\int_{0}^1\log_{e}\left(g(1-x)\right)dx$

$2\log_{e}L=\int_{0}^1\log_{e}\left(f(x)\right)dx+\int_{0}^1\log_{e}\left(f(x)\right)dx+\int_{0}^1\log_{e}\left(g(x)\right)dx+\int_{0}^1\log_{e}\left(g(x)\right)dx$

$\log_{e}L=\int_{0}^1\log_{e}\left(f(x)\right)dx+\int_{0}^1\log_{e}\left(g(x)\right)dx$

$\log_{e}L=\int_{0}^1\log_{e}\left(f(x)g(x)\right)dx$

Comment: In your attempt, surely at line 3, where you have $$\int_{0}^{1} \log{(f(1-x)g(x))}\,\mathrm{d}x,$$ you can split the integral into two and go straight to line 7? Also, I'm not sure if you can actually take $\log$ of $f$ or $g$, since you aren't guaranteed that $f$ and $g$ are non-zero: their codomains include $0$..

Comment: It seems there is a mistake in line 2 of your attempt, because  

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\log_{e}\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{r}{n}\right)g\left( \frac{n-r+1}{n} \right)\right)\neq\int_{0}^1\log_{e}\left(f(x)g(1-x)\right)dx$

You can not move $\log_e$ into the integral in that way.

Answer (score 2):

Let

$$x_n =\sqrt[n]{f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)g\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)+f\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)g\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)+...+f\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)g\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}.$$

Then

$$\log x_n = \frac{1}{n}\log\left(\sum_{k=1}^nf(k/n)g(1-k/n+1/n) \right) \\ = \frac{1}{n}\log\left(n\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(k/n)g(1-k/n+1/n) \right)\\ = \frac{\log n}{n} + \frac{1}{n}\log\left(\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(k/n)g(1-k/n+1/n) \right).$$

Hence

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \log x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log n}{n} + \left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \right) \log\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(k/n)g(1-k/n+1/n) \right) \\ = 0 + 0 \cdot \log\left(\int_0^1f(x)g(1-x) \, dx\right) \\ = 0
,$$

and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n = \exp\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \log x_n\right) = 1.$$

Note that the sum does not appear to be a conventional Riemann sum since $f(x)$ and $g(1-x)$ are not evaluated at the same intermediate points.  Nevertheless it converges to the integral as it can be written as

$$\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(k/n)g(1-k/n+1/n) \\ = \frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(k/n)g(1-k/n) + \frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(k/n)[g(1-k/n+1/n)-g(1 - k/n)].$$

Since $g$ is uniformly continuous, for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have $|g(1-k/n+1/n)-g(1 - k/n)| < \epsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(k/n)[g(1-k/n+1/n)-g(1 - k/n)] \right| \\ \leqslant \epsilon  \int_0^1|f(x)| \, dx.$$

Comment: What if $f= 0$? Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} 0 = 0$.

Comment: @Hetebrij: Thanks. That's true.  Otherwise ...